# Integrate .net application with Cisco Call Manager

Tags: asp.net, .net, tapi, jtapi

Does anyone know of a good .net wrapper for TAPI 2 or JTAPI? I need to integrate my asp.net application with Cisco Call Manager to handle some events like 'Call Ended'.

Answer (score 0):

you can user Julmar Atapi or itapi . it is free wrapper for accessing tapi.